# LoadGrammar Speech Recognition Error

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

This is the error message i keep getting on this line when I try to run:

```
recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(GrammarBuilder());
```

Error:

```
The language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer.
```

I have searched high and low for this but I cannot seem to find an answer!

I have two language options in the speech recognition property:

- Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - UK)
- Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - US).

My code will only work if I set the settings to English - US.

Is there a hidden setting on Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express that would let me change it from US to UK?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you will need to have your systems language set to `EN-US` for you to use the `Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - US)` option, as would the `EN-UK` system language, you will need to use the `Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - Uk)` option.

Comment: my system's local language is UK and my region is also UK! I am very confused on why it still shows and error